# Not able to update the checkbox using onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to Change the value of checkbox from false to true
onclick on checkbox the onchange is not getting called.

checkedbox should be changed to true whwn ever we clicked the checkbox

```
this.state = {
  checkedbox: false,
}

 render() {
 <Checkbox
   label="test"
   value={checkedbox}
   onChange={this.handelCheck}
  />
}



 handelCheck = (event) => {
this.setState({
  checkedbox: event.target.checked
});
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question with code from submitted answers. It makes your question pointless, and the answers meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one
change on the value in the Checkbox to

```
value={this.state.checkedbox}
```

and change the handelCheck to just change to

```
 !this.state.checkedbox
```

and it shold work

```
  this.state = {
      checkedbox: false,
    }
    
     render() {
     <Checkbox
       label="test"
       value={this.state.checkedbox}
       onChange={this.handelCheck}
      />
    }
    
    
    
     handelCheck = () => {
    this.setState({
      checkedbox: !this.state.checkedbox
    });
    }
```

Comment: still seeing the same issue

Comment: You should add details on what you've changed, and why. "Try this one" isn't a useful answer.

Comment: is this better?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `this.state` in value, try the following

```
value={this.state.checkedbox}
```

Comment: still seeing the same issue

Comment: Are you using any library for checkbox? if you do, what library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, try using `checked` attribute for checkbox

[Example](https://%5Benter%20link%20description%20here%5D%5B1%5Dhttps://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_checked2%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_checked2)

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends how you're logging that state after you've changed it. `setState` provides a callback that you can use to do things after the async process has completed, like logging the new state.
2. Depending on whether you're using a library or rolling your own `Checkbox` component, `checked` rather than `value` for your component property is much more meaningful.
3. You should be passing in the `checked` *state* to your `checked` property, not a random variable called `checked`.

In this short example I've created my own `Checkbox` component to show you how it all fits together.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { checked: false };
  }

  // Set the state, and the call the callback
  // function to log the new state
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ checked: e.target.checked }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.checked);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Checkbox
          label="test"
          checked={this.state.checked}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

};

class Checkbox extends Component {

  render() {
  
    const {
      checked,
      label,
      handleChange
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>{label}</legend>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </fieldset>
    )
  
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion maybe because it is not getting the event!

try :

```
onChange={e=>this.handelCheck(e)}
```

Comment: Incorrect, see @Ibrahim Azhar Armar 's answer for the real reason why... They aren't passing in the correct value they are just using the "checked" variable which is undefined, instead of using the state variable.